# C++: Animation: Normals: How to deal with large number of normals and updating them during animation update?

Tags: c++, animation, normals

My code (coded in C++) is bottle-necking in the for-loop that deals with updating the normals for the model. The model that I used to test has around ~2.2k vertices (indiced) which works fine and works under the 60 fps limit, but the normals are just as much as the indicer (~12k). The code works as intended, but this for-loop takes too long due to the amount of normals that must be updated.

The information is exported from the Maya API and stored into a file format that my project can read (there are no problems with my project reading the file; it's all correct).

Is there something that I am not thinking about to reduce the number of normals it must calculate? What tricks do people use in AAA to deal with such issues? Can it be optimized at Maya API level that I am over looking? Any other advice that could help would be greatly appreciated.

I have previously searched for answers, but I could not get away from "normal maps" coming up which has nothing to do with my issue. >.>;

Thanks in advance! :)

=============================================

Code block as requested:

```
        // Transform and save our normals.
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < p_mesh_data->getNormalCount(); ++i )
        {
            Quaternion total_rotation;

            unsigned int index = p_mesh_data->getNormalToVertex( i );
            for( unsigned int j = 0; j < p_skeleton->getJointCount(); ++j )
            {
                JointInfluence influence = p_mesh_data->getInfluence( index * p_skeleton->getJointCount() + j );

                total_rotation = total_rotation + ( rotations[influence.joint_id] * influence.weight );
            }

            p_normals[i] = Matrix( total_rotation ).transform( p_mesh_data->getNormal( i ) );
        }
```

Comment: Added the problematic code block.

Comment: Have you profiled this code to see what is taking the most execution time in the loop?

Comment: I just got the output, but it says it is too much for the post. :/

Comment: @ usep It is taking ~125 ms to get through with that loop. Without it, it's 16 ms.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the data and a little more research, I purged the weights less than 0.001f (basically anything that had no influence) which chopped down most of the loops needed to update the frame. Now it is sitting at a comfortable 16 average ms.

For anyone else that comes across the same issue, purging unneeded influences is a MUST in order to keep a high frame rate with complex/high poly models. On simple geometry, this may not be needed.

Thanks everyone that took the time! :)